# Java boolean expressions

Tags: java, boolean

I noted something weird for me in Java, I accidently tried to evaluate following Boolean expression

```
if (something = null && false) // error
if (false && something = null) // no error
```

Whether java compiler stops the evaluation of expression when he realizes that expression can not fulfill?

Comment: Both don't pass compilation. `null` cannot be an operand of a boolean operator.

Comment: The second one also gives a compilation error. What setup did you use that doesn't produce an error there?

Comment: Like Eran said: [both fail](http://ideone.com/x0ucKA).

Comment: Just like @eran said

Comment: Again `something = null` will not pass compilation. It should be `something == null`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can't convert between a `null` and a boolean type.

A Boolean expression is a Java expression that, when evaluated, returns a Boolean value: true or false.

As you have seen, Boolean expressions are used in conditional statements, such as `if`, `while` and `switch`.

To be clear, you can't even convert between integer and boolean type as commonly happens in many other languages like C.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why **false && null** doesn't give you any errors is because *false && whatever will always be false*, so that the compiler doesn't evaluate the second term of the operation, because it already knows the answer = false.

In the first case : **null && false**, the compiler evaluates the first term which is not a boolean, as the compiler expected for the '&&' operation. So it will throw an error.

Anyway, you should always check your variables before using them in boolean operations.

**EDIT**: Yes, I answered before the question was edited and yes, my answer is anyway wrong, I just checked(sorry for that). ***It will always throw an error if one of the operands is not a boolean.***

Comment: Funny. This question has 4 answers and two of them say that OPs example doesn't compile and the other two say something else and your answer gets two upvotes, although it is clearly wrong. Doesn't look like your friends voted for you, because they also don't know how Java works.

Comment: @Tom, OP has edited the question. Though edited code also has some mistakes but now it makes some sense unlike the previous one.

Comment: @SanketMakani And that edited code is still wrong, like this answer, which refers to the old version.

Comment: @Tom, Yes I have commented on the question about this.

Comment: @SanketMakani And if that second has been fixed as well, then there is no question anymore, because both version will compile successfully :D.

Answer (score 0):

Java checks the first operand of an and (&&) logical operator, if it is false, it will not evaluate the second operand. As well as for the or (||) Java checks if the first operand is true, then, it will not evaluate the second operand.

If you want both operands to be evaluated you can use bit operations instead (&, |)

Comment: Both the expressions does not compile

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `boolean` in if statement and `null` is not a `boolean` so both of the expression is wrong.

maybe you try to use :

```
if (something == null && false) 
if (true && something == null)
```

In this case both of them is correct.